# Selective iteration over configObj sections

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm having some issues iterating over sections in a configObj object. What I'm trying to do is iterate over a subset of the subsections in a section. When I run my code I get the error, "TypeError: 'Section' object is not callable".

Here's my code:

```
section = webconf['Items']
for subsection in section(range(1,3)):
   <code block>
```

What I'm trying to do is to avoid iterating over the 'DEFAULTS' subsection for that section. I suspect this is failing because the section is a dict whereas I've tried referencing it as a list. However, I am not sure how to cleanly achieve my goal when the object is a "dict" (or configObj.Section).

If someone can put me on the right track I'll greatly appreciate it:)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for subsectionKey in section.keys():
    if subsectionKey != 'default':
        # - do your code here
        # - subsectionKey is just a key (a string), so
        #   make use of it with section[subsectionKey]
```

Comment: Thanks:) I should have thought of that, but it is the New Year. My brain's probably still on holiday;)